# What does "I30 SEK" mean?

Tags: automobiles, fees-and-charges, sweden, amusement-parks

I noticed this sign: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Astrid_Lindgrens_World_Entrance.JPG

The "40 SEK" part makes sense. It means 40 Swedish kronor to park.

But then it says "I30 SEK" underneath for something they call "Quickstop". Whatever that means, I'm asking about the "I" in front of the "30". It's not a "1", so it doesn't say "130". It says "I30 SEK".

I've never seen this in any other context, anywhere. What does the "I" signify?

Comment: I think you are overthinking. If a stay in the day is 40 kronor, 130 for an overnight stay is reasonable. Either they have an odd font or they used the wrong key when making the sign. Or do you have proof from an other place.

Comment: Some fonts just make 1, I and l (small L) look very similar.

Comment: Google street view shows its been changed to 60 and 200 SEK, with the night rate from the earlier time of 19.00, and with the correct font for the 1.

Comment: @WeatherVane are you certain that it's 200 SEK rather than Z00 SEK?

Comment: @xngtng the font in this image does not appear to be among them.  The font here is a serif font, and the serifs clearly and unambiguously indicate an upper case `I`.  If the font uses that glyph for lower case `l` or the numeral `1` then the font is so poorly designed as to be incorrect.

Comment: @phoog sure, but less certain about the SEK :)

Comment: Perhaps more relevant, check out their official web site to see the current prices: https://biljett.astridlindgrensvarld.se/ticketshop/huvudsasong. Parking is 60 SEK/day.

Comment: @Lundin but google street view is from late 2020, I think the quickstop is still offered even if it is not on the web site

Answer (score 5):

> But then it says "I30 SEK" underneath for something they call "Quickstop". Whatever that means

Like the comments discussed, it is likely just an typographical error or confusion and 130 SEK was intended (apparently now it is higher). The font looks like a Garamond-type font (Adobe?) which in many versions may also confound 1 and I. Or someone just pressed the wrong key.

Quickstop means it is only available for short overnight stays during the specified hours for roadtrippers. It implies certain level of services (e.g. toilets, showers, electricities, water) but nothing is guaranteed. The rules may differ by location.

Comment: It may be worth noting that some old typewriters didn’t even have a “1” key, and people used a lowercase L which looked like 1 instead. Likewise some didn’t have a “0” key and people used O instead. There are probably people still used to that.

Comment: @jcaron I've only used such a typewriter once or twice, but I frequently confuse `o` and `0`, no doubt because of their proximity and because of the American habit of pronouncing `0` as "oh."  I don't much confuse `1` and `l`, though I have met people who do (both in person and through typed documents).  I haven't seen many instances where `1` and `I` have been confused, as they have been in this case.

Comment: Having learned to type on a typewriter without a one or zero key, my father caused a bug in a program he was writing that took him 3 weeks to find because he kept reading (lower-case ell) for a (one). It's a real thing!